# I have a question about using form_dropdown()

Tags: codeigniter

I have a question about using form_dropdown().

table:category

```
cat_id

cat_name
```

Controller:

```
function index()

{

$this->load->model('category_model');


$data['category'] = $this->category_model->cat_getallcat();


$this->load->view('category_input',$data);


 }
```

Model:category_model

```
    function cat_getallcat()

         {

     $this->load->database();

     return $this->db->get('category')->result();

        }
```

View:

```
<?php


$this->load->helper('form');


echo form_open('send');


$list[''] = 'Please select a Category';


foreach($query as $row)

 {

$list[$row->cat_id] = ucfirst(htmlspecialchars($row->cat_name));

 }


echo form_dropdown('category', $list);


echo form_close();

?>
```

error obtained:

```
  A PHP Error was encountered



   Severity: Warning


  Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()


  Filename: views/category_input.php


   Line Number: 28
```

Comment: foreach expects an array. `print_r($list)` - what output do you get?

Answer (score 1):

the `->result()` will return the first row only, so this function is what you want to loop over.

Model

```
function cat_getallcat()
{
    $this->load->database();
    return $this->db->get('category');
}
```

View

```
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
    $list[$row->cat_id] = ucfirst(htmlspecialchars($row->cat_name));
}
```

EDIT:
Also, you are sending the result as `$data['category']` then trying to access it as `$query`. So really the foreach would be `foreach($category->result() as $row)` in this example

Answer (score 1):

You are asking foreach to loop over $query, but I you haven't set $query as a variable anywhere that I can see.

Since you set $data['category'] to hold your query result() in your controller, you need to loop over $category in the view:

```
foreach($category as $row)
{
    $list[$row->cat_id] = ucfirst(htmlspecialchars($row->cat_name));
}
```